# SSIS SecurityNegotiationException: could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS (no certificate)

Tags: c#, ssis

I'm integrating with a webservice via SSIS.  I keep getting an error that appears to be a failure to communicate with a certificate.

When I run the exact same code just in a console, it works fine.

The service doesn't require a certificate, so is this a SSIS thing?  I'm new to SSIS so this might be a basic issue.

Exception:

```
System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority 'myurl'. --->
```

System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Code below:

```
    var wsBinding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.Transport);
    wsBinding.Name = "wsHttpBinding_GlobalCredentials";
    wsBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;

    
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate { return true; };

    EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("https://myurl/myservice.svc/Soap12_NoAuth");


    using (GlobalCredentialsClient globalCredentialsClient = new GlobalCredentialsClient(wsBinding, endpointAddress))
    {
        try
        {
            globalCredentialsClient.ChannelFactory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SslCertificateAuthentication = new X509ServiceCertificateAuthentication();                    
            globalCredentialsClient.ChannelFactory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SslCertificateAuthentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;

            
            GlobalAccount checkCredentialsResult = globalCredentialsClient.CheckCredentials(username, password);

            MessageBox.Show("Result: " + checkCredentialsResult.OrgID.ToString());

            Dts.Variables["sOrgName"].Value = checkCredentialsResult.Created;

            globalCredentialsClient.Close();
        }
        catch (CommunicationException ce)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Comms exc " + ce.ToString());
            globalCredentialsClient.Abort();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a hunch, it could be a mismatch between TLS versions. What .NET is the application that's failing?

You could try setting the TLS version right before the API Call.

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

or

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
```

Comment: Do not use TLS11 it has been disabled and will not work.

Comment: @jdweng I fully agree. Although,sometimes you need to support legacy systems

Comment: Five years ago the industry decided to eliminate TLS 1.0/1.1 because hackers were able to decipher messages.  Finally in June this year Microsoft pushed a security update on server that are disabled TLS 1.0/1.1.  Since the security update was pushed everybody has been forced to upgrade to 1.2/1.3 if they didn't in the last 5 years.  It is very unlikely that anybody is still using TLS 1.0/1.1.  Leaving TLS 1.1 can cause exceptions to occur when it fails.